# Flatness puzzle in a $\Lambda$-dominated Universe

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

Friedmann equation together with the acceleration equation yield

$\dot{\Omega} = (1+3w) H \Omega (\Omega-1)$.

The Flatness puzzle lies in the fact that $1+3w>0$, but how is this possible in a $\Lambda$-dominated era? Shouldn’t $w=-1$?

Answer (score 1):

$\Omega$ is the ratio of the energy density of the Universe to the critical density, $\Omega = \frac{\rho}{\rho_c}$, where $\rho_c = \frac{3H^2}{8\pi G}$.

The flatness problem (as I understand it) is the question why the value of $\Omega$ is so close to 1 today. The flatness problem is solved by allowing an inflationary epoch in the very early Universe.

Note that $\Omega = 1$ is a trivial solution to your conservation equation $\dot{\Omega} = (1 +3w) H \Omega (\Omega - 1)$ and $w$ can hence take any value.

The condition for cosmic acceleration (not related to flatness) is given by $1 + 3w < 0$.

This comes from the equation $\frac{\ddot{a}}{a} = -\frac{4\pi G}{3}(\rho + 3P)$, which we can rewrite in terms of the equation of state using $w = \frac{P}{\rho}$. We know we live in a dark energy dominated era, so $\ddot{a} > 0$, and hence acceleration occurs for $(\rho + 3P) > 0$, or $1 + 3w < 0$. With some rearranging we see that $-\frac{1}{3} > w$. So a $\Lambda$ dominated epoch where $w = -1$ satisfies the acceleration condition.

Comment: Yes you are right, my question is not very clear. The point is that if Lambda dominates, why $1+3w>0$?

Comment: @MiguelBolín I have edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry but I think, from the $\ddot{a}/a$ equation, the acceleration condition is $1+3w<0$.